Send timestamp with timezone via AJAX, getting it by PHP
Sending AJAX-Request:
        $.ajax({
            url: "./inc/del.inc.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: $("#frmMain").serialize() + "&data=" + JSON.stringify(data) + "&primary=" + primary_key,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(baseData) {
                console.log(baseData);
            }
        });    

The jQuery-AJAX-Request sends the data with '+' between time and timezone. Checked with developer tools.
data    '{"timestamp":"2024-04-10 12:32:00+02", ,.....}'

Getting the value from $_POST
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);

Already $_POST['data'] is without '+': 2024-04-10 12:32:00 02
How can I keep the '+' in PHP?
This leads to a problem, if I like to do database operations wiht this value.

timestamp is passed within the data. In $_POST['data'] the + is already lost

Can't reproduce using the provided data - demo: https://3v4l.org/4SUp4#v8.1.27 . I would assume the problem lies elsewhere - e.g. maybe the problem is in whatever is POSTing the data to php, if it is already missing the + before it reaches PHP. Please try to provide a [mre] of the issue including the code which is generating this data and sending the POST request. See also [ask]. Then we'll have a much better chance of helping you meaningfully.

P.S. If you're sending JSON in your HTTP request, I would suggest not wrapping it inside a form-url-encoded parameter. Wrapping one data format inside another is inefficient, messy, and usually not a logical thing to do. Occasionally it can also cause encoding issues. You can just send raw JSON from the client, and PHP can read that natively, with the right code (see Receive JSON POST with PHP for details)

Same as ADyson, using var_dump(json_decode('{"timestamp":"2024-04-10 12:32:00+02"}')); leads to the good value, you should edit the question to include how the Ajax request is sent, it's more likely a problem on this side. It may also come from a from a input sanitzation on the PHP side, but it's less likely (if you have some, add to the question too)

"How can I keep the '+' in PHP?" - by applying proper URL encoding to values you insert into a URL query string like that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Of course you would not have to deal with that yourself, if you simply added a hidden input field with name data into your form, and assigned the JSON as that field's value, before you make the AJAX request - then $("#frmMain").serialize() will include the value, and handle all necessary encoding for you.

Yep this seems to be a result of mangling data formats (JSON inside form-url-encoded - why??) and failing to URL-encode properly - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/djvzf68p/3/ (watch the Console, and also view the Payload of the request to the PHP script using the Network tool after you submit the form). + has a special meaning in a form-url-encoded paramter string (it encodes a space character). Easily fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/djvzf68p/4/. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

If I hadn't voted to close this earlier as lacking debugging details (before it was edited), I'd now be closing it as a duplicate of AJAX POST and Plus Sign ( + ) -- How to Encode? instead. There are probably other duplicates too

Solution:
$.ajax({
    url: "./inc/del.inc.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        formData: $("#frmMain").serializeArray(),
        row_data: data,
        primaryKey: primary_key
    }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(baseData) {
        console.log(baseData);
    }
});   

PHP
$post_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

